# How does web browser know about what connection to open, HTTP or HTTPs?

Tags: http, https

After clearing the browser cache, cookies and web related data. I simply typed Gmail.com in the URL field of the web browser and I captured the packets in wireshark.

I found that the web browser initiated the request for Gmail.com with dest. port as 443 (HTTPS).

I want to know how the web browser got to know that the web site has to be opened in HTTPS mode. I thought it will be sending the request first to port 80 (HTTP) and then there will be some sort of redirect or another handshake.

Answer (score 0):

That's because of [`Strict Transport Security`](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/HTTP_Strict_Transport_Security_Cheat_Sheet). A special header is set by the website indicating that it should only be accessible over `HTTPS`. Try opening it in a new incognito window and it will open over `HTTP`.

Here's a [`guide`](http://classically.me/blogs/how-clear-hsts-settings-major-browsers) how to clear HSTS in the major browsers. For example in Google Chrome you may try opening this url `chrome://net-internals/#hsts` and remove gmail.com from the HSTS cache.